# SQL Server Database Design - Should we normalize a key with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am designing a new database and specifically dealing with a set of elements with the following relationship.

1. Each SerailNumber (SNo) can have one or more Lanes (max Lanes =15)
2. Each Lane can have one or more Chambers (max Chambers =20) Each
3. Chamber can have one or more Units (max units = 4000)
4. Each Unit can have one and only one Value

So each Value is determined by a composite key (SNo, LaneNo, ChamberNo, UnitNo). If I were to put this in one table, it would look like this:

```
==========================================
| SNo| LaneNo | ChamberNo | UnitNo | Value |
==========================================
```

Since the number of Lanes and Chambers will be small the data type can be tinyInt. However since we can have 4000 units per Chamber, we will be repeating three columns (SNo, LaneNo, ChamberNo) 4000 times. My question is:

**Does the above design has any issues in regards to Normalization rules or how I built my primary key? Would putting (SNo, LaneNo, ChamberNo) in a separate table with a unique id and using that unique id as a key for UnitNo and Value be a better solution?**

I am looking for advice from folks with experience in using similar type of data dependencies.

Comment: What normalization guideline do you think a composite key might violate?

Comment: On one hand, such composite keys repeat data, as you already noted. On the other, you can now get the field migrated from the parent table, without actually JOINing with it. So both key designs have merits and the best you can do is measure on realistic amounts of data to determine which one fits your particular use-cases better.

Comment: One cannot normalize without identifying functional dependencies (when a column is a function of others) and join dependencies (ways that a table is equal to the join of projections of it). Your listing of N:Ms is not the requisite info. Also the mere fact that a given subtuple appears more than once in a table means nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Primary key selection is part of database normalization. First normal form requires that a primary key be selected. The primary key can be either a single column or multiple columns. You normally select a primary key based on your intended useage. The column or combination of columns must uniquely identify a single row (none of which can be nullable in SQL server).

Since the 2nd normal form defines related tables in term of foreign key relationships to the primary key on the parent table, it is very desirable (considered a requirement by many) that the columns making up a primary key never change in value.

Because of these, natural keys such as phone_number of social_security number are not used as primary keys because they do change (or were miskeyed initially). So, many people design tables with a surrogate key (e.g. an identity value) and use that everywhere. Personally, I am not pedantic about such, but rarely use a natural key unless it is tied to something very unlikely to change, such as US state codes. SSN is not a good choice due to other considerations such as duplicate SSN's (they do exist) and the fact that you should not expose SSN except when you have a legal justification for doing so.

Having a small primary key as opposed to multiple large columns is a definite performance advantage when joining records. You will often need a secondary index on the natural key columns though.

You might need to read an article on [basic normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). 3rd normal form is usually considered a best first approximation for best design.

Comment: Sorry, but your understanding of normalization seems to be incorrect. 1NF is not about keys (primary or otherwise) and 2NF is not (directly) about foreign keys (which are not keys, BTW). If you don't have a key, you don't have a relation (a set of tuples, as opposed to multiset of tuples), so you haven't even reached the 1NF yet. The linked article is incorrect - I suggest taking a look at Wikipedia instead. Other than that, you actually make some reasonable points!